# Simplest, cheapest solution for hosted A/B tests?

Tags: website-design, usability-testing, tools

I'd like to test two designs for the same call-to-action before deploying the winner in anger.

An ideal solution would host both designs on a single URL, record the results and generate usage reports.

So far I have found unbounce.com and verifyapp.com, both of which appear to do what I need, though verifyApp is still in beta and I don't yet have a login.

Has anyone here used these or similar services, and if so what were the results?

Comment: Try this post http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/tips-for-a-b-testing

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Google Website Optimizer](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer) as another option. I've not used it before, so I can't give a personal experience, but it's free and I've heard good things about it.

Comment: It certainly fulfills the "simple, cheap" part of the question.

Comment: A friend of mine at work actually just gave a cool tech talk on how to use it: http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/blog/post/How-to-do-AB-Testing-using-Google-Website-Optimizer.aspx

Comment: @JasonRR - nice tech talk, good explanation of the Groundhog Day problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Performable](http://www.performable.com/).

Personally, I really like Unbounce.

Comment: The link to Unbounce is http://unbounce.com/ but also consider @Zoltán's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following links might help you.

**Smashing Magazine** articles

[**The Ultimate Guide To A/B Testing**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/24/the-ultimate-guide-to-a-b-testing/) and 
[**In Defense Of A/B Testing**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/08/26/in-defense-of-a-b-testing/)

**Think Vitamin** article

[**The Business Case for A/B Testing**](http://thinkvitamin.com/business/the-business-case-for-ab-testing/)

Answer (score 1):

[Ninjabutton.com](http://ninjabutton.com/) - if you just want to measure buttons/calls-to-action

Comment: Nice idea they've got, provided you only want to A/B test your Calls to Action.

Comment: Yeah, I've started to see this type of idea pop-up for a variety of reasons, not the least of which is a search engine cannot crawl two different versions of the page.  It is guaranteed to match - the images that is shows would just be different.  

Definately has some merit.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is built on Ruby on Rails, then [A/Bingo might work for you](http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo). It's open-source (free) and sounds easy... I haven't personally used it though.

From their site:

> A/Bingo is a Ruby on Rails A/B testing framework written as a plugin. It is an extraction from Bingo Card Creator, where it is used in production. A/Bingo should work for most recent versions of both Rails 2.3 and 3.0.
>
> Key features:
>
> Test display or behavioral differences in one line of code
> Measure any event as a conversion in one line of code.
> Eliminate guesswork: test for statistical significance in one line of code.
> Blazingly fast, with minimal impact on page load times or server load.
> Written by programmers, for programmers. Marketing is an engineering discipline!